# PHP ADK installation for linux report server with Valentina

Tags: report

I have started using Valentina Studio as an alternative to Crystal Reports.

I'm having difficulty getting the PHP ADK Installed. I'm running Debian GNU/Linux 8.6 (jessie) on a Digital Ocean server. This box also has vserver running fine (I can connect from Valentina Studio remotely and all works well).

PHP & MySQL are setup and running well. PHP Version 5.6.17-0+deb8u1. I followed [these instructions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=roZiqELF9B4) for Installing Valentina for PHP ADK on Linux - I downloaded the file (Valentina PHP LIN 64 DEB) and extracted it using dpkg -i to /opt/VPHP/

I copied pdo56_valentina.so and php56_valentina.so to /usr/lib/php5/20131226

I edited /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and added the following lines:

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=php56_valentina.so
extension=pdo56_valentina.so
```

- I tried with and without "extension=pdo.so" as it is already loaded via /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
- I also tried creating a file and adding the lines within /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-valentina.ini

My phpinfo() does not show any of the Valentina files.

Answer (score 2):

Steps how to install VPHP on linux are shown in this video
 http://youtu.be/roZiqELF9B4

VPHP 5.6 files was broken on moment of question, they was replaced by files of VPHP 7.0. This was fixed next day after question asked.